# @Autowired usage in Annotation type declaration

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired, spring-annotations

I understand [@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) used for dependency injection

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

But what's the usage for Annotation type declaration that is defined

> ```
> @Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,METHOD,PARAMETER,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE})
> ```

Is there any usage/effect for defining `@Autowired` in custom annotation:

```
@Autowired
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

I didn't find any references in [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)

> By default, the autowiring will fail whenever zero candidate beans are available; the default behavior is to treat annotated methods, constructors, and fields as indicating required dependencies.

Comment: Simple supposition, but maybe it can be used as alias to @Autowired anotation ?

Comment: @OresteViron can you answer if it feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place `@Autowired` annotation above other annotation declaration, the new annotation will have the same effect as `@Autowired` annotation. For example, in your case you can use `@MyAnnotation` above constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

Moreover, you may discover, that `@Controller` annotation in spring framework declared as `@Component`. As result, classes that marked as `@Controller` also created as container beans.